# Swift REST API call in singleton class and use of protocol

Tags: ios, swift, singleton, nsurlsession, swift-protocols

I am calling rest api using `singleton` class as I need to call this api from 3-4 view controllers. To pass the data, I implemented one protocol method also. 
I am not sure this is the right way of passing data and use of singleton class. Could anyone please guide me in this? Please guide me if I am missing or doing wrong in the code. I appreciate your time and suggestions.

```
//This is my NetworkService class 

protocol NetworkServicesDelegate {
// protocol method
    func serviceData(arrayData:NSArray)
   }

class NetworkServices:NSObject{

static let sharedInstance = NetworkServices()

var delegate: NetworkServicesDelegate?
var dataArray: NSArray?

func getData(paramValue : String,apiName:String)
{
    let configURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().objectForInfoDictionaryKey("ConfigURL") as! String       
    guard let url = NSURL(string: configURL+"/"+apiName) else {
        print("Error: cannot create URL")
        return
    }

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:url)
    let defaultSession = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration())

    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    let params = ["myKey":paramValue]
    let valid = NSJSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(params)
    print(valid)

    request.HTTPBody = try? NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: [])

    let task = defaultSession.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data:NSData?, response:NSURLResponse?, error:NSError?) in

        if let HTTPResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
            let statusCode = HTTPResponse.statusCode

            if statusCode == 200 {

                self.dataArray = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: [] ) as! NSArray
                self.serviceData(self.dataArray!)
            }
        }

    })
    task.resume()
}

private func serviceData(serviceDataArray: NSArray){
        guard self.delegate != nil else {
        return
    }
    delegate?.serviceData(serviceDataArray)
        print("serviceDataArray : \(serviceDataArray)")
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you want to use singleton pattern here? Is the purpose of this class/getData function is simply to call a server api and get data?

Comment: @firstinq Yes, the purpose of this class/getData function to call a server api and get the data. As I am using `completionHandler`, I am not able to return the data. So I implemented singleton pattern and returned the data. 
That's what I am not sure about this, should I used singleton class or not. Please suggest suitable approach.

Comment: Please see the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow the following approach:

- Make a static or class function and take the delegate as an additional parameter
- Call the delegate function after the data is download from the api in competition handler.
- And from any of the view controller call this function like this:

  ```
  NetworkServices.getData("yourparam", apiName: "yourAPINAME", delegate: self)
  ```

Modified NetworkServices class code below.:

```
protocol NetworkServicesDelegate {
   func serviceData(arrayData:NSArray)
}

class NetworkServices:NSObject{
   class func getData(paramValue : String,apiName:String, delegate:NetworkServicesDelegate?)
   {
        let configURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().objectForInfoDictionaryKey("ConfigURL") as! String
        guard let url = NSURL(string: configURL+"/"+apiName) else {
        print("Error: cannot create URL")
        return
   }

   let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:url)
   let defaultSession = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration())

   request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
   request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
   let params = ["myKey":paramValue]
   let valid = NSJSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(params)
   print(valid)

   request.HTTPBody = try? NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: [])

   let task = defaultSession.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data:NSData?, response:NSURLResponse?, error:NSError?) in

        if let HTTPResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
            let statusCode = HTTPResponse.statusCode

            if statusCode == 200 {

                let dataArray:NSArray = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: [] ) as! NSArray

                delegate?.serviceData(dataArray)
            }
        }

    })
    task.resume()
  }   
}
```

Comment: Thanks @firstinq Yes I got it. Thanks for the updated code. 
Just need to add NetworkServicesDelegate protocol in above code.

Comment: Thats right. Additionally you might consider adding another method your protocol to handle error or no data situation.